# Is it possible to make all internal classes visible to another assembly in C# with some configuration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I know that is possible change the visibility with:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTests")]

namespace Foobar
{
    internal class Foo
    {
      //...
    }
}
```

So my test project can create the test for the class `Foo`. The problem is that  I have a lot of internal classes and I don't want to dirty them with that `assembly` expression. Is there another way of doing this `InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTests")` for the whole project?

Comment: Did you really mean all projects in the solution ? As @CodeCaster notes, the `InternalsVisibleTo()` attribute already does apply to all internal types in the project you place the attribute in.   If you want it to apply to all types in all projects within a solution, then you can put the attribute in a separate file by itself, in a separate folder in your solution space, and include it in all projects as an indirect reference.

Comment: I have two projects in the solution, one consist in UTests. And It works fine the solution of @CodeCaster. It seems the most simple in this case. What you say sounds interesting too but I have not too many projects by now. 

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`[InternalsVisibleTo]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute is an assembly-level attribute, meaning that if you define it once, it already applies to the entire assembly.

So that line you show only needs to be included only once in your project to apply to all internal types.

I'd recommend moving it to where the other assembly-level attributes are specified: in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in the Properties folder of the project.

Answer (score 5):

To expand upon the comment from @CodeCaster, the attribute should be placed in

```
AssemblyInfo.cs
```

in the Properties section of your project

e.g.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTests")]
```

you will also need to fully qualify the assembly name

e.g.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Foo.Bar.UnitTests")]
```

Comment: It doesn't matter where you place the attribute, so "should" is too strong of a word I guess.

Comment: Agreed,  should is possibly too strong but it seems to be the standard place for putting common assembly level attributes and the only place I've ever seen this one used.